# Explicitly assigning values to a 2D Array?

Tags: java

I've never done this before and can't find the answer. This may not be the correct data type to use for this, but I just want to assign an int, then another int without a for loop into a 2D array, the values will actual be returns from another function, but for simplicity I've just used int i and k, this is how I thought you'd do it, but its not:

```
int contents[][] = new int[2][2];
            contents[0][0] = {int i, int k}
            contents[1][1] = {int i, int k}
            contents[2][2] = {int i, int k}
```

TIA - feel free to point me in the direction of a better data struct to do this if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Why don't you make iteration over the array and assign via method call.?       for(...) contents[i][j] = {xMethod(), yMethod()};

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The best way is probably to just declare and assign all values at once.  As shown [here](http://www.java.happycodings.com/Core_Java/code26.html).
Java will automatically figure out what size the array is and assign the values to like this.

```
int contents[][] = { {1, 2} , { 4, 5} };
```

Alternatively if you need to declare the array first, remember that each `contents[0][0]` points to a single integer value not an array of two.  So to get the same assignment as above you would write:

```
contents[0][0] = 1;
contents[0][1] = 2;
contents[1][0] = 4;
contents[1][1] = 5;
```

Finally I should note that 2 by 2 array is index from 0 to 1 not 0 to 2.

Hope that helps.

Comment: voting up for most complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking to assign all values in a 2D array at declaration time?  If so, it works as follows:

```
int[][] contents = new int[][]{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

Remember that a 2D array in Java is really an array of arrays, but Java gives you some special syntax if you do this at declaration time.

Comment: In my case, I need this thing `public int[][] insert(int[][] intervals, int[] newInterval) {
        if (intervals.length == 0) return new int[][] { newInterval };`, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you want to assign a row in one statement?

After declaration like:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[2][2] //A
```

or

```
int[][] matrix = new int[2][] //B
```

You can use two kinds of assignment statement:

```
matrix[0][0]=1; //can only used in A, or will throw the NullPointerException.
```

```
matrix[1]=new int[] {3,3,5};//This can be used both in A and B. In A, the second row will have 3 elements.
```

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
int [][] t = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

Answer (score 1):

contents[0][0] points to a single int, not an array of ints.  You can only assign a single value to any particular index into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
int contents[][] = new int[2][2];
contents[0][0] = 1;
contents[1][1] = 2;
...
```

That will let you individual assign values to elements in your 2D array, one at a time.

Also note that you cannot access index 2 in an array of size 2. An array of size 2 has 2 valid indicies (0 and 1). In general, an array of size N has N valid indicies (0...(N-1))

Comment: Yep sorry that was just a typo in my example.