# Java multi-dimensional array instantiation

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explicitly assigning values to a 2D Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318113/explicitly-assigning-values-to-a-2d-array)

sorry if this has been addressed before.  I did a search and couldn't find anything:

Is there any way to instantiate a 2D array in Java with values like in the manner of a 1D array.  For example, is there a way to do this:

```
int[] oneD = {1, 2, 3};
```

for this:

```
int[][] twoD = ...?
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
int[][] twoD = { {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3} };
```

Comment: I tried passing this as a parameter but it didn't work `myMethod({{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}});`. The method takes a two dimensional array of ints. Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

It is really a set of sets so it is intuitive that it works like so:

```
int[][] twoD = { {1,2,3}, {3,4,5} };
```

Note that as for 1D arrays, spacing is up to the user. The Java tutorials actually give an example of multi-dimension array initialisation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is simple and intuitive:

```
int[][] twoD = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

This would result in a 2-by-3 integer array.