# How can I loop over the entire array and fetch it?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D Array that's data is being fetched from an Enum.

```
*Enum Params*
int[][] items
```

And I have a method which accepts 2D Arrays as one of its arguments.

The object is to iterate through all the rows and columns of the 2D Array
and fetch its values.

```
*The Method Im Using Currently*
    public void sendItemsOnInterface(TeleportData data1) {
            resetItemGroups();
            for(int i = 0; i < data1.getItems().length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < data1.getItems()[i].length; j++) {
                    int[][] rewards = {{data1.getItems()[i][0], data1.getItems()[j][1]}};
                player.getPA().sendScrollableItemsOnInterface(28229, rewards);
            }
        }
    }
```

However its only showing the first part of the array, as in its not showing the entire elements of the array.

The array is listed in this format
0 = Item 
1 = Amount.

I'm trying to list all the items and amounts.

Comment: `int[][] rewards =....` creates a new array each iteration of the inner loop. I think you want that in the outer loop. Or move `player.getPA()....` to the inner loop?

Comment: So... where is the enumeration "enum"? Also, where is the method that accepts the Integer 2D array?

Comment: so initilize rewards outside of the loop? and the ```player.getPA()``` is used to access the method that accepts the 2D Array as its arguments

Comment: ```   player.getPA().sendScrollableItemsOnInterface(28229, rewards);
``` This is the method that the 2D Array is being passed through. And data1.getItems[][]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried you code but,
Try this might work

```
for (int i= 0; i< data1.length; i++) {
        for (int j= 0; j< data1[i].length; j++) {
            data1[i][j] = row * col;
            System.out.print(data1[i][j] + "\t");
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Appreciate your help However I had a question it works as intended when I do This; ``` int[][] rewards = {{995, 1},{13, 1}, {4155, 10}, {11802, 2}, {995, 2}, {4155, 2}, {1, 100}}; player.getPA().sendScrollableItemsOnInterface(28229, rewards);```  But when i try fetching the data for the 2D Array from the enum it doesn't seem to work any idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is something you'd wanna do, but if don't need the indexes of the arrays, you should iterate. I'm going crosseyed reading your for loops :)

```
    for (int[] row: data.getItems()) {
       for (int col: row) {     
              // do your stuff
        }
    }
```

Elaboration further:

```
int[][] rewards = {{data1.getItems()[i][0], data1.getItems()[j][1]}}
```

you are assigning a single row to the rewards array with alternate (i and j) row indexes.... and I hate this web editor! >:( an hour to try to get this written out because I hit backspace and it loses focus and goes back a page on my browser :p

```
int contents[][] = { {1, 2} , { 4, 5} };
```

Stole that from another stack overflow post/answer at :[Explicitly assigning values to a 2D Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318113/explicitly-assigning-values-to-a-2d-array)

Comment: Appreciate your help However I had a question it works as intended when I do This; ```   int[][] rewards = {{995, 1},{13, 1}, {4155, 10}, {11802, 2}, {995, 2}, {4155, 2}, {1, 100}};
      player.getPA().sendScrollableItemsOnInterface(28229, rewards);```

Comment: But when I try fetching the data from the enum it doesn't seem to work, any idea as to why?

Comment: int[][] rewards = {{data1.getItems()[i][0], data1.getItems()[j][1]}}; you're using a row index and a column index (i and j) when I don't think I should be in there

Comment: Err to elaborate better - you are referencing [ROW][COL] --- the ROW dimension with both I and J variables